# No se registra el uso de CPU en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, rendimiento, webapi

Estoy tratando de verificar el uso de CPU para algunos llamados a un API construida en C# .NET 5; el problema es que la herramienta de diagnostico no me muestra el árbol de llamados ni el uso de CPU por cada método del árbol, también lo intente con el generador de perfiles de rendimiento y nada.

Dejo los recortes de pantalla, para hacerme entender mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

para ver el detalle tenes que poner un breakpoint. Cuando ejecutes esa llamada podrás ver que la solapa de CPU comienza a llenarse con información.

[image: Ver que al poner breakpoint, la solapa de CPU se completa]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente lo hice como indicas pero aún así no me muestra el uso de CPU. Encontré información sobre un problema que se tiene con los PCs que tienen GPU NVIDA. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598268/visual-studio-2019-diagnostic-tools-always-say-there-is-no-data-in-the-current. Ya repare la instalación de VS 2019 pero tampoco funciono.

Comment: Tengo GPU NVIDIA (GT 650M) y he trabajado con otras sin problema. Se me hace que viene por otro lado. En la solapa de output no te da ningun mensaje o descripcion? Que tipo de proyecto es? Probaste crear una solucion vacia a ver que pasa?

Answer (score 0):

Ahora si me funciona, lo único que hice, fue descargar e instalar la última actualización de Windows 10 (KB4023057).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]